# Java: How to implement the interface?

Tags: java, monads

What is the simplest and workable implementation of the interface of `M`. And how to implement method `flatMap`?

```
public interface M<T> {

    <U> M<U> flatMap(Function<T, M<U>> f);

    M<T> unit(T t);

}
```

I'm stuck in `flatMap` implementation.

```
M<String> m = new M<String>() {

    @Override
    public <U> M<U> flatMap(Function<String, M<U>> f) {
        return null; // ?
    }

    @Override
    public M<String> unit(String s) {
        return new M<String>() {
            @Override
            public <U> M<U> flatMap(Function<String, M<U>> f) {
                return null; // ?
            }

            @Override
            public M<String> unit(String s) {
                return null; // ?
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: What is flatMap meant to do?

Comment: What are the specifications for `M` -- what should the methods do? Usually this info is in the JavaDocs of the `interface`.

Comment: It should map a function to `M` instance.

Comment: @MickMnemonic any action accept `return null`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The methods `flatMap` and `unit` return `M`. Without at least one preexisting concrete implementation of `M` you couldn't do this using anonymous classes without at some point just returning `null`.